# What's the best way to use data.table inside a function in R?

Tags: r, performance, data.table

I a have function that uses the `data.table` syntax. The function works but is **way** too slow.
I know there has to be a better way to do this. This is my function and some setup for reproducibility:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
sw <- data.table(starwars)

# Large data-set to make difference noticeable
for (i in 1:15) {
  sw <- rbind(sw, sw)
}

# My working but slow function
dt.fun <- function(expr) {
  
  sw[, .("mean_bin" = mean(eval(parse(text = expr)),
                                             na.rm = T)),
              by = species]
}
```

The function takes an expression and calculates the mean of that expression within each species.
The function must be able to take any expression that a regular user could type in the command window, i.e. it must be able to calculate all of the following:

```
dt.fun("height > 150")

dt.fun("hair_color %in% c('brown', 'blond')")

dt.fun("mass")
```

The problem is that my function takes too long and is clearly not leveraging `data.table`'s power:

```
# Using dt.fun()
tictoc::tic()
dt.fun("height > 150")
tictoc::toc()
# 2.23 sec elapsed


# Inputting the expression myself
tictoc::tic()
sw[, .("mean_bin" = mean(height > 150, na.rm = T)),
   by = species]
tictoc::toc()
# 0.28 sec elapsed
```

My questions are:

- How can I rewrite my function so that it's faster?
- What other improvements would you make?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How can I get the starwars data?

Comment: Use env var to specify columns in expression from variable, instead of eval parse or get. 1.14.3+

Comment: @jangorecki thank for all your comments. I looked through the article of programing with `data.table` and realize that the `env` argument is very powerful. However I am still not 100% sure how I can pass different expressions into `j` perhaps using `substitute2` ? but there must be a simpler way. If you could provide an answer that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I replicate your finding that your dt.fun is ~1/10 as fast as using hardcoded expressions. I don't have the sw data. My sample data has 1.6 million rows, and data.table is using 32 cores.

```
tic(); sw[,mean(duration>60),group]; toc()
...
0.323 sec elapsed

tic(); dt.fun('duration>60'); toc()
...
3.205 sec elapsed
```

Pre-parsing the expression makes no difference:

```
dt.fun <- function(expr) {
    parsed=parse(text = expr)
    sw[, .("mean_bin" = mean(eval(parsed),na.rm = T)), group]
}
tic(); dt.fun('duration>60'); toc()
...
3.832 sec elapsed
```

Pre-defining the function makes up all or most of the difference:

```
f1=eval(parse(text='function(duration)duration>60'))
dt.fun1 <- function(f) {
    sw[, .("mean_bin" = mean(f(duration),na.rm = T)), group]
}
tic(); dt.fun(f1); toc()
...
0.341 sec elapsed
```

Pre-defining the function dynamically also works:

```
expr='duration>60'
f1=eval(parse(text=paste0('function(duration)',expr)))
tic(); dt.fun(f1); toc()
...
0.339 sec elapsed
```

Using eval once per expr instead of inside the data.table j-expression solves the problem, e.g.,:

```
dt.fun <- function(expr) {
    f = eval(parse(text=paste0(
            'function(sw) sw[,.("mean_bin" = mean(',expr,',na.rm=T)),group]'
        )))
    f(sw)
}
tic(); dt.fun('duration>60'); toc()
...
0.33 sec elapsed
```

PS: If this is for a web application, you indeed shouldn't use eval(parse...)) because of the risk of code injection. Instead, you could implement an accepted list of operators and column names. For example, something like:

```
allowed_operators = c('+', '–', '*', '/', '^', '%%', '%/%', '<', '>', '<=', '>=', '==', '!=', '!', '&', '&&', '|', '||')
cols = colnames(sw)
if(
  length(operator)==1 && length(operands)==2 &&
  operator %in% allowed_operators &&
  (all(is.numeric(operands) | operands %in% cols))
){
    env=list(.cond=call(operator, as.name(operand[1]), operand[2]))
}
```

...but of course this severely limits the set of handled expressions. (ref: jangorecki's comment below.)

Comment: This usage should be avoided as explained in https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/articles/datatable-programming.html

Comment: Thanks for the link! What answer would you give?

Comment: Using language objects rather than eval parse. Or ideally plugging language objects into env var.

Comment: `env=list(.cond=call(">", as.name("duration"), 60))`

Comment: @webb thsnk you for your response! starwars is from tidyverse, I have updated the post to reflect this.

Comment: @jangorecki could you provide a full answer?

Comment: Feel free to use info from my comments and write an answer.

Comment: @jangorecki, thing is your response is only valid for the operation `duration > 60`. Which is too narrow a use case for my problem. I have looked the documentation you provided, besides it saying that `eval(parse(...))` should be avoided there is not enough information relevant to this issue on how to program for the general case. Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: If this is for a web application, you indeed shouldn't use eval(parse...)) because of code injection. I'll update my answer to discuss this.

Comment: @webb, it is not for a web application so I'm not worried about code injection but I do like to always follow best practices. If you could update your answer that would be great! I was thinking of using a formula to mass on to `mean()` but I haven't been able to make it work.

Comment: Forgot to mention, but there is also a big problem with @jangorecki 's solution, mainly that it doesn't work. `env` and `substitute2` [are not yet a part of](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/5369) `data.table`. Guess that's why he couldn't provide an example. Hopefully the next release of `data.table` will come soon so we may all tryout these new features!